# Adding Custom control to another custom control

Tags: delphi, custom-controls

What i am trying to accomplish is to create new touchkeyboard.

First i created buttons which i derive from speed buttons. 
That done, now i need to create multiple buttons and layout them somewhere. This is were i get stuck.

I created a new component which i derive from TGraphicControl (this should be my new touchkeyboard), but i don't know how to add components to canvas. I actually don't know whether i'm supposed to add them to canvas or to some other component (eg. panel)!?!

Is my approach OK?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your wording and confusion between Panel, Canvas and custom controls in general, I assume you're a Delphi beginner. You need to learn about frames: [embarcadero docwiki link on frames](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/creatingframes_xml.html)

Frames allow you to create re-usable portions of GUI. You use the IDE to "draw" the frame, you can then place that composite control (the frame) onto forms or other frames. It's a very powerful feature and it's conceptually very close to what other languages call "custom controls" (very close to what asp.net or WPF consider a custom control to be).

In the Delphi world, when you say "custom control", people would normally expect you to want to create an reusable control that's placed in a package and it's installed in the IDE. It's an fairly advanced subject. If that's what you want then I misunderstood the question, sorry.

Comment: I'd have said frames were most likely a bad idea here. I imagine we can just wait a little while until Mr Rejbrand comes along with one of his custom controls.

Comment: The OP is talking about building a "touch keyboard" using speed buttons. You can do that with frames straight into the IDE, no code required. But sure, one of Rejbrand's custom controls is better, especially if he posts some pictures.

Comment: @David, @Cosmin: It would be *really* easy for me to write a control that displays an English on-screen keyboard, with mouse hover effects, etc., and with support for visual themes and, also, support for the cases where themes are disabled. It could be double-buffered. Some research, however, would be necessary to support the keyboard layout of the end-user, which we have no *a priori* knowledge about. In addition, you have to manage keyboard focus in a special way, and this way depends on where the custom control is placed. I don't have time for this today, I am afraid.

Comment: But naturally, a custom control *is* the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

If you're creating a custom visual control, you need to create the buttons and position them manually. For example:

```
TOnScreenKeyboard = class(TWinControl)
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent);
end;

[...]

constructor TOnScreenKeyboard.Create(AOwner : TComponent)
var
  TempButton : TSpeedButton;
begin
  inherited;
  TempButton := TSpeedButton.Create(self);
  TempButton.Parent := self;
  TempButton.Top := 10;
  TempButton.Left := 15;
  TempButton.Caption := 'A';
end;
```

You can put the button creation into a loop and position each one according to where it should be.

(I wrote this off the top of my head, and I don't write a lot of Pascal anymore, so there may be some minor mistakes! But it should get you started.)

Comment: That code's wrong, because an `TGraphicControl` can't be the parent of a `TSpeedButton`. The parent needs to be an `TWinControl` descendant. At a minimum you should derive TOnScreenKeyboard from TCustomControl (or TWinControl itself, or TCustomPanel). I'm not downvoting because I'm sure you'll fix it.

Comment: Fixed, though with your rep you could have fixed it yourself. :-)

Comment: Yeh, but if I fixed it myself I'd then have to ask for half the upvotes. +1.